# Chrome Extension:Trigger Click Even from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have to trigger a `click` and `mouseover` event from script (file within a chrome extension). 
To achieve the goal, I wrote the following script

```
var elem = $('li .js-dropdown-content').find('li a[data-action=favoriteOrUnfavorite]');
console.log(elem)
elem.mouseover().click();
```

It prints the log (HTML Element Object) on console But, the events are not triggering.

But, It gets triggered when I copy/paste the code in console.

**Note**: There is no Javascript/jQuery conflict, Extension Script is being loaded after `document_end`

Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I was on "Wrong Console Context" that's why it was working when I copy/paste the code on console.
So, Its not working either from console when selecting the correct console for the extension.

Comment: try `elem.trigger('click')`

Comment: not worked either!

Comment: try warping jquery `$(elem).trigger('click')`

Comment: I did so.......

Comment: Sorry, its not even working from console. Just updated the question

Comment: check if `$(elem).length` is greater than 0

Comment: Yes it is.. thats why I gets the object in the console. When doing console.log()

Answer (score 0):

OP already answers his question, but adding this gif to help the newbies, trust me I know the pain, if someone stumbles here it might help

[image]

Comment: I've already mentioned in the question that I was on "Wrong Console Context" but, changing the context doesn't not works.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, did your included JQUERY in chrome extension? Your webpage might have JQuery but not the content script(scripts that you defined in extension manifest )

Comment: nop. actually, I have added both. jQuery and myownscript.js. `myownscript.js` has the code that I mentioned in question.

Comment: Are you sure that the element you are clicking has not disabled non trusted event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. btw, one workaround I found so far is to append javascript directly to the page and it works